# Calling Perl variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, mason

```
owner_sel.onChange = function(){
    if(this.form.state_id.value ==  <%= $STATE_NEW %> ) {
        this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_ASSIGNED %> ;
    }
}
```

I believe I'm calling the Perl variable wrong.

I currently have this code which checks if a select value is `$STATE_NEW` and if it is then switch it to `$STATE_ASSIGNED` but it is not working.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my call. Thanks

Comment: Can you view the javascript in your browser to see what values for those variables are output (I assume you're using some Perl templating library like Embperl, Template Toolkit...)

Comment: Maybe you wanna check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578194/how-to-pass-perl-variable-into-javascript-function

Comment: What does the generated Javascript look like? What templating system are you using in Perl?

Comment: FYI: you are generating JavaScript code in a template, and generally that's just a bad practice (you can no longer serve static minified Javascript files). Instead, write values into a `data-*` HTML attribute, and pull them out of the DOM: `<div id="states" data-state-new="<%= $STATE_NEW %>" data-state-assigned="<%= $STATE_ASSIGNED %>"></div>`, then with jQuery you can read these as easily as e.g. `$('#states').data('state-new')`.